# CodeIgniter / Image Moo - Dynamic output is not rendering anything at all

Tags: image, codeigniter

I was wondering if anyone has any experience with the Image_Moo library for Codeigniter.

I have integrated it with my CodeIgniter project quite well except for one function.

That function is the save_dynamic() function.

When i run the following code, it doesnt display anything at all, not even errors .. The following code is what i have in my View.

```
<?php $this->image_moo->load("/photo-1.gif")->resize(100,100)->save_dynamic(); ?>
```

If anyone has used this library, i would love some help.

Cheers,

Comment: Have you tried `if($this->image_moo->errors) print $this->image_moo->display_errors();` ? Have you looked through the CI forum: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/161469/ ? What versions are you using?

Comment: Have you ever figured this out? I have the same problem. I will say that its possible $this will not see the CI instance, in the view.  (It does in the controller.)

Answer (score 1):

call it from a controller

```
public function show_image($width,$height,$text,$bordersize,$watermark='on',$directory,$location)
{


    $this->image_moo
    ->load($directory . '/' . $location)
    ->make_watermark_text($text, "assets/machine.ttf", 65, "#fff")

    ->resize($width,$height);
    if ($watermark == 'on') {

    $this->image_moo->watermark(6)
    ->watermark(7);
    }

    $this->image_moo->border($bordersize,"#FFFFFF")
    ->border(2,"#000000")       
    ->save_dynamic();
}
//usage: http://localhost/xampp/index.php/upload/show_image/1200/600/Jason/5/on/uploads/72198_1671772401137_5046618_n.jpg
```